# rdlc report in pdf is not displayed correclty

Tags: rdlc

I have one rdlc report and rendered it in a web page using microsoft's reportviewer control. This report contains mutiple tables to display records. When I export this report to PDF, the text in one table displayed over the other table texts (texts behind other texts). Is there any settings for the table to display it one below other? Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

It has been my exoerience with Microsoft's report renderers (both the Report Viewer and Reporting Services), that only the most simple layouts will render correctly in all the supported formats.

Tweaking the report only gets you to about 90% or 95%, but you will find that you cannot solve certain display inconsistencies by fixing the report design.

The workaround is to have different report definitions (RDLC files) for each output format that you have to support.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the tables or any other controls do not overlap in your report design. The behavior is sometimes caused by overlapping controls.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar case and found out that it was related an overlapping control in my report, I was given a hint in results windows after the compilation, it was something like this:

> ContratoOnline.rdlc : warning rsOverlappingReportItems: Los objetos
>   ‘line17’ de tipo line y ‘textbox54’ de tipo textbox se superponen. No
>   todos los representadores admiten la superposición de elementos de
>   informe.

After correcting this, i could generate the PDF report without any issue.
Hope it helps